# mongodb json validation is not working in standalone mongo

Tags: mongodb, validation, json-schema-validator

I have standalone mongo setup, I added collections script with all validation but validation was not working.. so tried this [mongo guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/), and did similar steps but validation is not working. it is accepting the document.

I executed below collection script

```
db.createCollection("students", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "name", "year", "major", "gpa", "address.city", "address.street" ],
         properties: {
            name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            gender: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is not required"
            },
            year: {
               bsonType: "int",
               minimum: 2017,
               maximum: 3017,
               exclusiveMaximum: false,
               description: "must be an integer in [ 2017, 3017 ] and is required"
            },
            major: {
               enum: [ "Math", "English", "Computer Science", "History", null ],
               description: "can only be one of the enum values and is required"
            },
            gpa: {
               bsonType: [ "double" ],
               description: "must be a double and is required"
            },
            "address.city" : {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            "address.street" : {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   validationLevel: "strict",
validationAction: "error"
})
```

then Executed below query .

```
db.students.insert({
   name: "Alice",
   year: NumberInt(2019),
   major: "History",
   gpa: NumberInt(3),
   address: {
      city: "NYC",
      street: "33rd Street"
   }
})
```

got below response

```
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

but I am expecting validation error.

```
WriteResult({
   "nInserted" : 0,
   "writeError" : {
      "code" : 121,
      "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
   }
})
```

Do I need to enable something in mongodb setup?

My mongo version is

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.18
```

Comment: Please be more precise. What means "is not working". What schema did you define? What was the json you wanted to validate? What output did you get and what did you expect?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an example of the collection validation you have created as well as the document that should be rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to replace "gpa: NumberInt(3)" line as  "gpa:3"

```
 db.students.insert({
   name: "Alice",
   year: NumberInt(2019),
   major: "History",
   gpa: 3,
   address: {
      city: "NYC",
      street: "33rd Street"
   }
})
```

I hope it works